# Access Angular Factory through Injection

Tags: angularjs, controller, code-injection, factory, route-provider

I cannot get access to methods in my Angular Factory? I get "TypeError: Object # has no method 'method1'" error. My angular app looks like this...

*myApp.js*

```
var myApp = angular.module('myAngApp', [])

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/list',
      {
        controller: 'ListController',
        templateUrl: 'partials/list.html'
      })
     .when('/reports/:reportId',
      {
        controller: 'DetailController',
        templateUrl: 'partials/report.html'
     })
})
```

*factory.js*

```
myApp.factory('factory1', function(){

    var factory = {}; 

    factory.method1 = function() {
            console.log('method1');
        }

    factory.method2 = function() {
            console.log('method2');
        }

    return factory;

});
```

*ListController.js*

```
function ListController($scope, $location, $http, $route, $rootScope, factory1) {
  factory1.method1();
}

ListController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$route', '$rootScope', 'factory1'];
```

Comment: have you tried using the myApp.controller syntax for this?

Comment: not sure what you mean?

Comment: Maybe I'm accessing the factory incorrectly or I have not declared the factory properly? Because the error is...
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'method1'

Comment: the factory is declared correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
myApp.controller('ListController', [
  '$scope',
  '$location',
  '$http',
  '$route',
  '$rootScope',
  'factory1',
  function ($scope, $location, $http, $route, $rootScope, factory1) {
    factory1.method1();
  }]);
```

instead of your current function ListController and the $inject statement

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NuCZz/

Comment: With this syntax, how do I add ListController to .config()
    .when('/list',
        {
          controller: 'ListController'
templateUrl: 'partials/list.html'
      })

Comment: it's registered and will look it up - working on a fiddle now.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks. I applied your syntax and produced an error that showed I had a second ListController.$inject statement in my DetailController file which should have been DetailController.$inject Your syntax works and my original does too.

Comment: You're welcome. Sounds like a copy and paste error :)